# How is Vue.js and Vue.min.JS compiled?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, transpiler

I'm am trying to understand the directives that produce the output `/dist/vue[.min].js` file(s). While looking in `node_modules` folder, I see `/dist` and  `/src` folders.  The `/src` folder contains `index.js`. If I were to follow the dependency tree all the way through, would that result in the dist file? If the compiler is present, or the rules, in the `vue` package. I would appreciate if someone could point this out (and also verify/debunk my understanding of how the output file is produced).

Comment: In short, you want to understand how does `src/index.js` in Vue's repo being compiled into `dist/vue[.min].js`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  really the purpose being to get a clear understanding of the transpiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *build tool* is actually responsible for creating the *vue.min.js* file. In case if you are *not using* any build tool then you need to use the *minified version of vue.js* file from the *Vuejs site*.

Also the vue.js gets created using the *mode* value of **process.env.NODE_ENV** variable.

You can have more details of this from the [Production Deployment](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html) docs from the Vuejs site.

The rest of the details regarding the dir structure given in the *vue.config.js* config file.